# ffmpeg amerge and amix filter delay

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, filtering, ip-camera

I need to take audio-streams from several IP cameras and merge them into one file, so that they would sound simaltaneousely.

I tried filter "amix": (for testing purposes I take audio-stream 2 times from the same camera. yes, I tried 2 cameras - result is the same)

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 -map 0:a -map 1:a  -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3  -ar 22050 -vn -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1
```

result: I say "hello". And hear in speakers the first "hello" and in 1 second I hear the second "hello". Instead of hearing two "hello"'s simaltaneousely.

and tried filter "amerge":

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 -map 0:a -map 1:a  -filter_complex amerge -ar 22050 -vn -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1
```

result: the same as in the first example, but now I hear the first "hello" in left speaker and in 1 second I hear the second "hello" in right speaker, instead of hearing two "hello"'s in both speakers simaltaneousely.

So, the question is: how to make them sound simaltaneousely? May be you know some parameter? or some other command?

P.S. Here is ful command-line output for both variants if you need them:
amix:

```
[root@minjust ~]# ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202 -i rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202 -map 0:a -map 1:a -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0 -vn -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1       ffmpeg version N-76031-g9099079 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.032000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 20 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Data: none
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.032000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 20 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:2: Data: none
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (g726) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:1 (g726) -> amix:input1
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x2689600] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0x2727c60] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0x2689600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[NULL @ 0x268c500] RTP: missed 38 packets
[rtsp @ 0x2689600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[NULL @ 0x268d460] RTP: missed 4 packets
[flv @ 0x2958360] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x2958360] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
size=      28kB time=00:00:06.18 bitrate=  36.7kbits/s
video:0kB audio:24kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 16.331224%
```

and amerge:

```
[root@minjust ~]# ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202 -i rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202 -map 0:a -map 1:a -filter_complex amerge -vn -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1
ffmpeg version N-76031-g9099079 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.064000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 20 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Data: none
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:12345@172.22.5.202':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.032000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 20 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:2: Data: none
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x3069cc0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x3069cc0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 22050 Hz, stereo, s16p (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (g726) -> amerge:in0
  Stream #1:1 (g726) -> amerge:in1
  amerge -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x2f71640] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0x300fb40] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0x2f71640] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[NULL @ 0x2f744a0] RTP: missed 18 packets
[flv @ 0x3058b00] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x3058b00] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
size=      39kB time=00:00:04.54 bitrate=  70.2kbits/s
video:0kB audio:36kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.330614%
```

Thanx.

UPDATE 30 oct 2015: I found interesting detail when connecting 2 cameras (they have different microphones and I hear the difference between them): the order of "Hello"'s from different cams depends on the ORDER OF INPUTS.
with command

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://cam2 -i rtsp://cam1 -map 0:a -map 1:a -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0 -vn -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1
```

I hear "hello" from 1st cam and then in 1 second "hello" from 2nd cam.

with command

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://cam1 -i rtsp://cam2 -map 0:a -map 1:a -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0 -vn -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1
```

I hear "hello" from 2nd cam and then in 1 second "hello" from 1st cam.

So, As I understand - ffmpeg takes inputs not simaltaneousely, but in the order of inputs given.
Question: how to tell ffmpeg to read inputs simaltaneousely?

Comment: did you test with local file, not streaming input?

Comment: yes, but I didn't paid attention to delay. What will it give us? even if there is no delay with "input files" - I need "no delay" with streams. Anyway - the first "hello" taken from the cam is syncronized with video from the same cam. But the second (late) "hello" - taken from the same camera - is somehow late. (((

Comment: well, I tried mixing two identical files 1.mp3 and 2.mp3 (it is the same file with different names) ----- ffmpeg -i D:\1.mp3 -i D:\1.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3  -ar 22050 -vn -f flv D:\3.flv ----- - the result is perfect. so, how does it help us?

Comment: see update for the question at the end.

Comment: any resolution for this question? I would think that ffmpeg filter "amix" ( see http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix ) would perform what you might expect - a "mix" of audio where audio is layered on top of other audio ... not the "append" that your (@UserNew) testing shows that is actually performing. In that case it looks like "amerge" is the filter you actually are needing ( see http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1 )

Answer (score 0):

If using amix with two local file work perfectly, you can't make to play two audio at once.

When the input is from local file or streaming, ffmpeg know exactly its start time. so it can be mixed into one audio.

But when the input is from **Live** streaming, ffmpeg doesn't know exactly "when it starts" so start time should be different in different streaming URL.

More Important thing is that ffmpeg does not support concurrency when handle input. that's why order of "hello" depends on order of inputs.

I just know one solution to solve this. Adobe FMLE(Flash Media Live Encoder), which support **time code** when using RTMP streaming. You can get time code from both live streaming, then you can finally mix two audio into one.

Perhaps, you can start with this article : http://www.overdigital.com/2013/03/25/3ways-to-sync-data/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
 [a1][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3[a] \
-map [a] -ar 22050 -vn -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1
```